# How to use Django's ORM to update the value for multiple keys in a JsonField using .update() method?

Tags: python, django

I have a model field I am trying to update using Django's `.update()` method. This field is a JsonField. I am typically saving a dictionary in this field. e.g. `{"test": "yes", "prod": "no"}`

Here is the model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # {"test": "yes", "prod": "no"}
    extra_data = models.JSONField(default=dict, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am able to update a key inside the dictionary using this query (which works fine by the way):

```
Question.filter(id="123").update(meta_data=Func(
                        F("extra_data"),
                        Value(["test"]),
                        Value("no", JSONField()),
                        function="jsonb_set",
                    ))
```

The question now is, is there a way I can update the multiple keys at once(in my own case, two) using the `.update()` as shown in the above query?

I want to use the `.update()` method instead of `.save()` to achieve this so I can avoid calling a post_save signal function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: it's gonna look ugly.

I have done this in the past although in pure SQL, not using Django. The idea was to recursively call `jsonb_set()`. Each call would set one key.

So in SQL, to set the keys `{"test":"yes","prod":"no"}` you would do something like this:

```
UPDATE question SET meta_data = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(extra_data, '{test}', '"yes"'::jsonb), '{prod}', '"no"'::jsonb)
WHERE id = 123;
```

Please note that there are two nested calls to jsonb_set, the innermost using `meta_data`, and the outermost receiving the result of the innermost.

So the Django equivalent would look something like this (beware, not tested):

```
Question.filter(id="123").update(
    meta_data=Func(
        Func(
            F("extra_data"),
            Value(["test"]),
            Value("yes", JSONField()),
            function="jsonb_set",
        ),
        Value(["prod"]),
        Value("no", JSONField()),
        function="jsonb_set",
    ))
```

Or you could make a recursive function that returns that mess for you, setting one item at a time:

```
def recursive_jsonb_set(original, **kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        key, value = kwargs.popitem()
        return Func(
            recursive_jsonb_set(original, **kwargs),
            Value(key.split('__')),
            Value(value, JSONField()),
            function="jsonb_set")
    else:
        return original

Question.filter(id="123").update(
    meta_data=recursive_jsonb_set(F("extra_data"), test="yes", prod="no", other__status="done"))
```

Note the `'__'` feature to update subkeys.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Your recursive suggestion worked well!

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers, here is how I managed to solve the issue.

If you want to update just a single record, then you can do it this way which works fine:

```
question = Question.objects.filter(id="123")
question.update({
    extra_data={
    **question[0].meta_data,
    "test": "no",
    "prod": "yes",}
```

If you want to update multiple records then kindly take a look at the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77808989/8022306) (image below). The recursive function will help to update multiple keys in a JsonField.[image: Image showing a screenshot of the accepted answer]